# Why can I not import load_dotenv?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to code a simple discord bot in python, but it says i cant import load_dotenv, instead giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Rotomi/Rotomi.py", line 5, in <module>
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
ImportError: cannot import name 'load_dotenv' from 'dotenv' (/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dotenv/__init__.py)
```

For reference, here is my current code: https://pastebin.com/75qru00R

Comment: there are two modules `pip install dotenv` and `pip install python-dotenv` (which have `load_dotenv`). Maybe you installed wrong module

Comment: Ahh, that’s probably it. Thank you!

Comment: correction there is `dotenv`, `dotenv-python` and `python-dotenv` (and few others).  [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) has `load_dotenv`

Comment: @furas yeesh... that collection sounds ripe for a typosquatting attack.

Answer (score 17):

Just ran into the same issue and luckily we got it solved.

The problem is the package itself.
So instead of install package **dotenv**, what you should install is **python-dotenv**.

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

After that, you code shall work

Comment: just to add to the confusion... it's `python-dotenv` NOT `dotenv-python`

Answer (score 6):

Since `load_dotenv` is declared in `main.py` of the package, I simply imported it and used the function like that and it worked.

```
from dotenv import main
import os

main.load_dotenv()

print(os.getenv('access_token'))
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case : I uninstalled dotenv-python and dotenv first by following commend

```
pip uninstall dotenv-python
pip uninstall dotenv
```

and after install python-dotenv module by

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Comment: Worked for me with pipenv. There were some problems with a locally and globally installed version as well but after uninstalling and reinstalling everything it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this still needs to be solved, but I found out that this worked for me:

```
from dotenv import dotenv_values
temp = dotenv_values(".env")
TOKEN = temp["DISCORD_TOKEN"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I came here as I faced the same issue. I did my code according to [this tutorial](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) but

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

caused this error:

> *** ImportError: cannot import name 'load_dotenv' from 'dotenv' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dotenv.py)

The import itself worked:

```
(Pdb) import dotenv
```

But the suggestion didn't:

```
(Pdb) from dotenv import Dotenv
*** ImportError: cannot import name 'Dotenv' from 'dotenv' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dotenv.py)
```

Apparently also in my case I had to complete another install: `pip3.7 install python-dotenv --user`.
Yet, `from dotenv import Dotenv` would not run. The tutorial is correct in stating:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

I assume this could be a Python 2/3 transition error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost embarrassed to write this but I had forgotten to close then re-open VSC after running the correct command:

```sh
pip install python-dotenv
```

then

```py
from dotenv import load_env
```

Answer (score 0):

According to there official docs from https://github.com/pedroburon/dotenv ,
You import **Dotenv** not **load_dotenv**.

```
>>> from dotenv import Dotenv
>>> dotenv = Dotenv('/path/to/.env')
>>> print dotenv
{"FOO": "bar", "Bar": "baz"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6.9

With api-token = '123456' in the .env file in the root of your project.

```
import dotenv
dotenv.load_dotenv()
import os
token = os.environ.get("api-token")

print(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

My propblem was that my IDE was using the wrong python version .

Fixed here:

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-dotenv

Answer (score 0):

#### Simply import from from `main` class/sub-package  like this:

```py
from dotenv.main import load_dotenv
```

##### Configuration file for the application:

```py
dotenv_path = Path(".local.env")
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=dotenv_path)
```

> Maybe in your **`config.py`**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom.  My problem was a file *tokenize.py*, which overrode Python's `tokenize` module.  Renaming my file fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, uninstalling and reinstalling python-dotenv fixed the issue.